# are expanded war files faster?

Tags: web-applications, jetty, filesystems, performance

I'm using embedded jetty to launch a web application which I have currently packaged as a war file.  At first I was trying to prevent my war file from being expanded; then I began to wonder:

**Q:** is there some advantage for jetty to expand the war file contents?

And even if its slower...

**Q:** how can I prevent jetty from expanding it (or at least expanding it every time).

My setup looks like this:
I have set the I/O temp dir, via the JVM setting (`-Djava.io.tmpdir=deploy/temp`) after noticing that my JSPs were being thrown into the Windows temp directory.

```
<bean id="myAppContext" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <property name="contextPath" value="/myApp" />
    <property name="war" value="${my.warfile.name}" />

    <!--
    <property name="extractWAR" value="false" />
    <property name="copyWebDir" value="false" />
    <property name="parentLoaderPriority" value="true" />
    -->

    <property name="extraClasspath" value="deploy/config" />
</bean>
```

I tried setting the various options on the jetty WebAppContext (they are not well documented in jettty 7 javadoc btw).  They didn't seem to do anything helpful, so I commented them out.

Comment: Pretty much every major servlet container will unpack WARs before executing them. Reading from a JAR is *much* slower than reading from a local file.

Comment: You have a strong argument, but most of the app servers I have seen call this 'development' mode; it doesn't necessarily mean its faster.